# extension 'ms-vscode.vscode-selfhost-test-provider' wants API proposal 'testContinuousRun' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am not able to install any extensions. I'm on a Macbook Pro with Ventura (13.3.1). After getting the error I have tried manual download/install of .vsix files and get the same errors. Here is the console output:

```
*2023-04-10 08:25:39.992 [warning] Via 'product.json#extensionEnabledApiProposals' extension 'ms-vscode.vscode-selfhost-test-provider' wants API proposal 'testContinuousRun' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.
2023-04-10 08:25:40.005 [warning] Via 'product.json#extensionEnabledApiProposals' extension 'ms-vscode.remote-repositories' wants API proposal 'contribEditorGutterMenu' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.
2023-04-10 08:25:40.006 [warning] Via 'product.json#extensionEnabledApiProposals' extension 'github.vscode-pull-request-github' wants API proposal 'contribEditorGutterMenu' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.
2023-04-10 08:25:40.006 [warning] Via 'product.json#extensionEnabledApiProposals' extension 'ms-toolsai.jupyter' wants API proposal 'notebookControllerKind' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST. Likely, the proposal has been finalized (check 'vscode.d.ts') or was abandoned.
2023-04-10 08:25:40.404 [info] Started initializing default profile extensions in extensions installation folder. file:///Users/coronsa/.vscode/extensions
2023-04-10 08:25:40.720 [info] Completed initializing default profile extensions in extensions installation folder. file:///Users/coronsa/.vscode/extensions
**2023-04-10 08:25:41.483 [error] Could not find category with ID: Intermediate: Error: Could not find category with ID: Intermediate**
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2548:53844
    at g.invoke (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:145)
    at o.deliver (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:2121)
    at l.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:1729)
    at B.progressStep (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1896:27216)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1896:27411
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at B.progressByEvent (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1896:27395)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1896:22618
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1896:22536
    at g.invoke (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:145)
    at o.deliver (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:2121)
    at u.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:1729)
    at u.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:3215)
    at n.setContext (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:613:48543)
    at l.reset (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:613:46972)
    at new l (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:613:46867)
    at n.createKey (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:613:47849)
    at E (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:613:51621)
    at h.invokeFunction (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:615:360)
    at w.k (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1570:13475)
    at w.executeCommand (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1570:13037)
    at w.$executeCommand (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1579:638)
    at b.N (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1593:15228)
    at b.M (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1593:14946)
    at b.H (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1593:14039)
    at b.G (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1593:13020)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1593:11808
    at g.invoke (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:145)
    at o.deliver (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:2121)
    at l.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:1729)
    at u.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:556:15210)
    at G.onmessage (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1691:1489)
2023-04-10 08:25:43.458 [info] [perf] Render performance baseline is 37ms
2023-04-10 08:26:26.141 [error] Could not find category with ID: Setup: Error: Could not find category with ID: Setup
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2548:53844
    at g.invoke (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:145)
    at o.deliver (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:2121)
    at l.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:1729)
    at B.progressStep (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1896:27216)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1896:27411
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at B.progressByEvent (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1896:27395)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1896:22015
    at g.invoke (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:145)
    at o.deliver (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:2121)
    at l.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:1729)
    at w.k (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1570:13520)
    at w.executeCommand (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1570:13037)
    at Hs.J (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:619:6711)
    at Hs.H (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:619:4841)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2297:90263
2023-04-10 08:26:26.142 [error] Could not find category with ID: SetupWeb: Error: Could not find category with ID: SetupWeb
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2548:53844
    at g.invoke (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:145)
    at o.deliver (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:2121)
    at l.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:1729)
    at B.progressStep (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1896:27216)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1896:27411
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at B.progressByEvent (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1896:27395)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1896:22015
    at g.invoke (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:145)
    at o.deliver (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:2121)
    at l.fire (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:86:1729)
    at w.k (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1570:13520)
    at w.executeCommand (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:1570:13037)
    at Hs.J (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:619:6711)
    at Hs.H (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:619:4841)
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:2297:90263
**2023-04-10 08:34:00.586 [error] CorruptZip: end of central directory record signature not found
    at yt.download (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:93:141)
    at async j.y (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:93:20893)
    at async j.h (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:93:18962)
2023-04-10 08:34:00.613 [error] end of central directory record signature not found: CorruptZip: end of central directory record signature not found
    at yt.download (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:93:141)
    at async j.y (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:93:20893)
    at async j.h (/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:93:18962)
***
```

I have tried to uninstall/re-install VS Code (version 1.77.1) numerous times, but I get the same errors. I'm not sure what else I can try.

Answer (score 0):

If you google "`"'product.json#extensionEnabledApiProposals' extension 'ms-vscode.vscode-selfhost-test-provider' wants API proposal 'testContinuousRun' but that proposal DOES NOT EXIST"`", you'll probably find the following VS Code issue ticket as the top search result: [Insiders console warnings #178482](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/178482). This points toward this issue ticket in the [vscode-selfhost-test-provider](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-selfhost-test-provider) repo: [fix: remove now-stabilized continuous test run proposal
#24](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-selfhost-test-provider/pull/24). That fix was merged into the main branch on March 28 2023. At the time of this writing, the latest release tag of vscode-selfhost-test-provider was made on March 27 2023.

So just wait a bit for the fix in the extension to be released. For the time being, try downgrading VS Code and see if that works around the issue. Or if you don't actually need/want this extension, you can uninstall it.

Answer (score -1):

Not trying to promote any third party apps but I would recommend you to use [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) to uninstall and remove vscode related files completely and then reinstall again.

Make sure you install the M1 version of vscode as well.